# Different line-spacing for tables

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm writing my thesis with double-spacing however I would like my tables to be formatted with onehalf spacing. Is there a way to do this?
I am using \tabular for my tables.

I used \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} and following your advice I have tried doing the following: \begin{table}[H] \setspace{single} \centering \begin{tabular}{lcccc} \toprule \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\textbf{Text}\ \midrule Text & text & text & text & text\ \bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{table}\ however rather than changing spacing it adds "singlespace" to my table, could you help?

Comment: Without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), we even don't know how you've activated double-spacing. So I can only assume using package `setspace`, which also provides, e.g., environments like `singlespace`. You can put your `tabular` environment inside such a `singlespace` environment. If you are using a `table` environment, you can also use `\setspace{…}` inside the `table` environment.

Comment: @cabohah- I used  \usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} and following your advice I have tried doing the following: 
\begin{table}[H]
\setspace{single}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\textbf{Text}\\
\midrule
Text & text & text & text & text\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}\\

however rather than changing spacing it adds "singlespace" to my table, could you help?

Comment: @cabohah- re my above comment. I set the spacing in the preamble of the document, before \begin{document}

Comment: @pozzo -- Please include your code directly in the question.